# Converting a text file to JSON using Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a text file which contains:

```
b770d5b4bb6b594daf985845aae9aa5f:b0cb46d2d31cf044bc73db71e9865f6f
a6cde1a737b44799ad78f1c1df3bcc2d:77aa72de248cf3649d052a49995c0c84
555040e976be48cebea579309f4e6339:2b0003ca52ffc309ef76872c5ab3729c
```

Which code in Python could be used for converting the text file to a JSON file looks like this:

```
[
{
"kid": "b770d5b4bb6b594daf985845aae9aa5f",
"hex_key": "b0cb46d2d31cf044bc73db71e9865f6f"
},
{
"kid": "a6cde1a737b44799ad78f1c1df3bcc2d",
"hex_key": "77aa72de248cf3649d052a49995c0c84"
},
{
"kid": "555040e976be48cebea579309f4e6339",
"hex_key": "2b0003ca52ffc309ef76872c5ab3729c"
}
]
```

Comment: you could read each line and split by `:` to get the kid and key pair, then create the dict and append to a list

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. It is important for the community that you demonstrate that you are *also* working to solve your problem. the best way to to do that is to include the **text** based version of the code you have tried so far, even if it is not working quite right.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can read each line, split it with `':'` and build a dictionary with these two values. Then append the dictionary to a list. Finally you can use `json.dumps` to convert your Python object(list) to a string which is in JSON format.

```py
import json

res = []
with open('<Path to file.txt>') as f:
    for line in f:
        kid, hex_key = line.strip().split(':')
        res.append({'kid': kid, 'hex_key': hex_key})

print(json.dumps(res))
```

output:

```
[{"kid": "b770d5b4bb6b594daf985845aae9aa5f", "hex_key": "b0cb46d2d31cf044bc73db71e9865f6f"}, {"kid": "a6cde1a737b44799ad78f1c1df3bcc2d", "hex_key": "77aa72de248cf3649d052a49995c0c84"}, {"kid": "555040e976be48cebea579309f4e6339", "hex_key": "2b0003ca52ffc309ef76872c5ab3729c"}]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this code worked for me.